# Android. Поиск или фильтр в RecyclerView

Tags: android, поиск, recyclerview, filter, фильтр

Коротко о проблеме.
Решил попробовать использовать RecyclerView. Готового решения поиска как listView, там нет, нужно самому все реализовывать.
Так вот решения я нашел, если кому нужно внизу будет исходник, но есть проблема.

Есть список в нем отображаются заголовки, при нажатии на любой пункт перехожу во второе активити где уже есть заголовок и полное описание.

Реализовал я это так:

В MainActivity Я загружаю из БД (использую Sugar ORM) заголовки и id

```
        ArrayList<String> arrTitle = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Contact contact:allContacts){
        arrTitle.add(contact.title);
    }

    ArrayList<String> arrId = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Contact contact:allContacts){
        long  i = contact.getId();
        String str = Long.toString(i);
        arrId.add(str); // or arr.add(contact.name); if it's public
    }
```

Затем передаю их в Адаптар

```
mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(arrTitle,  arrId);
```

в Адаптаре RecyclerAdapter
Я получаю эти значению, заголовок вывожу в список, а id передаю во второе Активити

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    // преобразую id в массив
    idTab = new String[mId.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i != mId.size(); i++) {
        idTab[i] = mId.get(i);
    }

    // позиция элемента
    final int idvadaptere = position;
    // выводим на экран заголовки, в RecyclerView
    holder.mTextView.setText(mDataset.get(position));

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Context context = v.getContext();
            Intent ddddd = new Intent(context, LastActivity.class);
            ddddd.putExtra("id", idTab[idvadaptere]);
            context.startActivity(ddddd);
        }
    });
}
```

Во втором Активити LastActivity
Я получаю id и на основе этого id вывожу уже значения в текстовые поля

```
     // получаем Intent извликаем из него объект
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    // извлекаем из него объект
    idString = intent.getStringExtra("id");
    // конвертируем id в число
    idInt = Integer.parseInt(idString);


    // выводим текстовые поля
    Contact title = Contact.findById(Contact.class, idInt);
    String titleStr = title.title;
    textView.setText(titleStr);

    Contact prich = Contact.findById(Contact.class, idInt);
    String prichStr = prich.prich;
    textView2.setText(prichStr);
```

Проблемма в том, что если ввести в поиске некий заголовок, то в списке позиция этого заголовка будет уже не пятая к примеру, а первая и id уже будет другим, во второе активити значения подставять не с пятого id а уже с первого

Исходник поиска, он отлична работает, если кому нужно копируйте, единственная проблемма это передача данных при нажатии на пункт списка

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
```

...>

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/search_view"
      android:layout_gravity="right"
      app:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
      app:searchIcon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"/>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
private SearchView searchView;
```

в onCreate

```
        searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String text) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String text) {
            mAdapter.filter(text);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

**RecyclerAdapter.java**

// заголовки

```
private ArrayList<String> mDataset;
private ArrayList<String> mCleanCopyDataset;
```

Конструктор

```
    // конструктор
public RecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<String> dataset) {
    mDataset = dataset;
    mCleanCopyDataset = mDataset;
}
```

Поиск

```
    // В методе filter() мы перебираем все пункты списка и, если какой-то пункт содержит искомый текст, то мы добавляем его в новый список mDataset:

public void filter(String charText) {
    charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    mDataset = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (charText.length() == 0) {
        // mCleanCopyDataset у нас всегда содержит неизмененную и неотфильтрованную (полную) копию данных списка
        mDataset.addAll(mCleanCopyDataset);
    } else {
        for (String item : mCleanCopyDataset) {

           // мы перебираем все пункты списка и если какой-то пункт содержит искомый текст, то мы добавляем его в новый список mDataset
            if (item.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) {
                mDataset.add(item);
            }
        }
    }
    // метод notifyDataSetChanged() позволяет обновить список на экране после фильтрации
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте заменить `ddddd.putExtra("id", idTab[idvadaptere]);` на `ddddd.putExtra("id", idTab[holder.getAdapterPosition()]);`

Comment: Попробовал, не помогает

Comment: ID - уникальный идентификатор, который жестко привязан к каждой записи в БД. Он не может изменяться с изменением позиции. То что вы используете - все, что угодно, но не ID, где вы его берете?  Так же я так и не смог понять, почему ID у вас строка.